# Is there a "limit" to Task.WhenAll?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, async-await, .net-6.0

If I need to perform IO-operations in a loop, I can create the `Task`s and them await them all. Something like this:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for (var dataToProcess in listOfData) {
    tasks.Add(DoSomeIOAsync(dataToProcess));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

How can I reason about what a reasonable number of `dataToProcess` in `listOfData` is?

If `DoSomeIOAsync` is async, then the thread used would be returned while waiting for the IO. So no risk for thread pool starvation I guess?

Is it the overhead of having a large amount of `Task` state machines in memory that might be a problem?

Are there some guidelines that I can use to reason about this?

Comment: "*How can I reason about what a reasonable number of dataToProcess in listOfData is?*" -- depends on what resources you have available. A gut feeling says that 100's is definitely fine, 1000's is probably OK, 10,000's might be pushing it a bit, millions probably means you need another approach. But it really depends on the tasks and your available resources, so you'll have to do some testing

Comment: "*If DoSomeIOAsync is async, then the thread used would be returned while waiting for the IO. So no risk for thread pool starvation I guess?*" -- Correct

Comment: "*Is it the overhead of having a large amount of Task state machines in memory that might be a problem?*" -- Again, define "large". It's going to be much cheaper than having the same number of threads. Each Task will only use a small number of small objects, so I'd expect, again, you could happily get to 10,000's of tasks without worrying. But, you'll need to do some testing.

Comment: What kind of IO operation is it you are doing?

Comment: At some point, you're almost certainly going to overload whatever IO is being used here, so I'd say the answer to this entirely depends on what you are doing. There's probably a hard limit somewhere that you'll never hit, but doing more than a couple of hundred operations at the same time would likely be problematic I suspect.

Comment: For this sort of question, I'd usually suggest you assume no limit unless or until you encounter an *actual problem*. The chances that you're going to correctly *guess* at the location of a performance bottleneck and already know that it's related to the number of tasks being waited upon are slim to none.

Comment: I'd also expect IO to be overloaded before your `Task`s take up too much memory. Certainly if this is disk-based you will very quickly overload it, and even network operations can be overloaded at full bore.

Comment: Let's say that the optimal size for the `listOfData` is 10, how are you going to use this information? Do you have a larger set of data, and you are splitting it to chunks, and then you `Task.WhenAll` each chunk sequentially?

Comment: Thanks all! Good info. @Magnus, In this case, the IO is sending messages to Azure Service Bus (via MassTransit) and the amount of tasks would be ~1000. It sounds to me like what might end up being a problem, is if Azure Service Bus can handle that messages at once, which I think it should...